# JsonSerializable. Custom function for field, dependencing other field of current class

Tags: json, flutter, dart, json-serializable

I want to set a value to a field depending on another field of the same class.
For example, I have classes Team and Project:

```
class Team {
    String name;
    String curator;
    //etc.
}

class Project {
    List<Team> teams;
    List<String> curators;
    //etc.
}
```

JSON for "Project":

```
{
    "сommands": [
        {
            "name": "team 1",
            "curator": "curator 1"
        },
        {
            "name": "team 2",
            "curator": "curator 2"
        },
    ],
    //etc.
}
```

JSON does not have a "curators" field. I need the data for this field to be taken from "teams" (or key "сommands"):

```
["curator 1", "curator 2"]
```

But field "teams" should also depend on key "сommands".

I tried doing this:

```
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class Project {
    @JsonKey(name: 'сommands', fromJson: curatorsFromJson)
    List<String> curators;

    @JsonKey(name: 'сommands')
    List<Team> currentTeams;
    //etc.
}

List<String> curatorsFromJson(dynamic data) {
  // logic
}
```

But I got the error "More than one field has the JSON key for name 'сommands'."

How can I set the value of a field depending on another field when deserializing?

Comment: You need to provide different key & can you share the json response body

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh I added json example

Comment: `сommands` will return List of Team, and then you can iterate to get the  List<String> curators

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh yes, it's simple, but I can't use the same key for More than one field. How can deserialization bypass this limitation?

Answer (score -1):

You can get `curators` from `currentTeams`. Therefore you don't need to add jsonKey on curators.

```dart
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class Project {
  final List<String> curators;

  @JsonKey(name: 'сommands')
  final List<Team> currentTeams;

  Project({
    required this.currentTeams,
  }) : curators = currentTeams.map((e) => e.curator).toList();

  factory Project.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$ProjectFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ProjectToJson(this);
}
```

And `Team` will be (already have the default name as key).

```dart
@JsonSerializable()
class Team {
  String name;  
  String curator;

  Team({
    required this.name,
    required this.curator,
  });

  factory Team.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$TeamFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$TeamToJson(this);
}
```

And get data like `Project.fromJson(jsonDecode(data))`.